# How to get the Aurelia ViewModel from a DOM Element

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I remember reading some days ago about a method to get the ViewModel of a component let's say, starting from the DOM node.

I guess those elements are those that have a `au-target` class on them (added by Aurelia).

I've searched on google / documentation but did not manage to find anything.

So, how can I get the ViewModel of that element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you're looking for this:

```
this.element.au.controller.viewModel
```

Comment: Nope.. I mean, let's say I have a weird use case where I can get a DOM element which I know it's the HTML / template of a Custom Element. I don't have access to that VM because it's in a different module, far away.

Can I do something like HtmlElement.au.view-model that would return me the object / VM ?

Comment: Does `this.element.au.controller.viewModel` work for you ?

Comment: yes, this is it :) found it already but if you can update your answer i can accept it.

Comment: Sure! Thank you!